# Is it possible to use a global variable with $(this)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, this

I have a series of click events that I want to grab the text of their respective sibling.

In this case I am setting `id` to the output of `$(this).siblings('div').children('p.item_name').text()`, which is different for every item.

Is there a way to globally set `$(this).siblings('div').children('p.item_name').text()` so that I can just assign `id` to the same variable?

```
$('.buy').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).siblings('div').children('p.item_name').text();
    shoppingClickHandler('buyItem', id);
})

$('.try').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).siblings('div').children('p.item_name').text();
    shoppingClickHandler('tryItem', id);
})

$('.suggest').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).siblings('div').children('p.item_name').text();
    shoppingClickHandler('suggestItem', id);
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a function:

```
function getId(item) {
    return $(item).siblings('div').children('p.item_name').text();
}
```

Then you could just do, for example,

```
$('.buy').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Old Version:
    // var id = $(this).siblings('div').children('p.item_name').text();
    // New Version:
    var id = getId(this);
    shoppingClickHandler('buyItem', id);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the `shoppingClickHandler` call in a function that does the id lookup internally:

```
function dynamicShoppingClickHandler(action, node) {
    var id = $(node).siblings('div').children('p.item_name').text();
    shoppingClickHandler(action, id);
}

$('.buy').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    dynamicShoppingClickHandler('buyItem', this);
})

$('.try').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    dynamicShoppingClickHandler('tryItem', this);
})
```